# Que signifie « t'ar » ?

Tags: sens, oral, registre-familier

Dans la phrase

> t'ar ta gueule à la récré !

de la chanson *J'ai dix ans* d'Alain Souchon ? Je sais le sens de la phrase, mais je ne sais pas quel est le mot dans sa graphie normale.

Comment: http://youtu.be/OQlasqvqwj0 Voici la chanson :)

Comment: Avec l'accent ça se prononce plus comme *tu'har*.

Answer (score 30):

Rétablissons les parties qui ont été contractées ou omises :

> 1) *t'ar ta gueule à la récré !*
>
> 2) ***Tu vas voir*** ta gueule à la récré !
>
> 3) *Tu vas voir **dans quel état sera** ta gueule **après la raclée que je vais te mettre** à la récré(ation) !*

Comment: T'vas voir l'état d'ta gueule après c'qu'j'vais t'foutre à la récré.

Comment: @Istao Ca sent le vécu. (+1)

Comment: Ici, la contraction utilisée par Souchon a pour but d'imiter l'accent populaire (en enfantin) parisien.

Answer (score 4):

Je pense que "tar" est la contraction paresseuse de "tu vas voir", mais je préfère "tahar", plus proche de la prononciation dont j'ai le souvenir.

Answer (score 2):

J'avais toujours entendu *tarte ta gueule à la récré*, que j'interpètais comme  *je vais foutre des tartes sur ta gueule à la récré*.

Comment: Quoi qu'il en soit l'image est plaisante...

Comment: @RomainVALERI, je ne pensais pas à l'entarteur, mais au fait que _tarte_ a un acception dans le champs sémantique commun de _baffe_, _gnon_, _mandale_, _beigne_, _calotte_, _châtaigne_, _claque_, _coup_, _gifle_, _soufflet_, _taloche_, _tape_, _torgnole_, _marron_, ...

Comment: tant qu'à lister ...ajoutons *taquet, avoine, quiche*.

Comment: Ou encore un *pain*, un *bourre-pif*, une *pêche*.

Answer (score 2):

Dans les années 70 à Paris l'expression à la mode parmi les jeunes était « tu vois ». On commençait toutes les phrases  par : « Tu vois ...»  comme une forme d'interjection anaphorique . Avec l'accent populaire parisien (titi) traînant  cela devenait rapidement « tu wois » puis « tu wa » et bientôt « twa. » Selon la même  évolution, avec le même accent, le « tu vas voir ta gueule à la récré » devient « Twar ta gueule à  la récré. » J'utilise le **w** pour traduire l'allongement du mot qui traduit le côté traînant de l'accent parisien de l'époque comme dans le « ouais » (oui) très à la mode aussi à la même époque  et qui à Paris s'allongeait encore plus en « Wouais. »

Answer (score 0):

J'ai toujours entendu Gare à ta gueule dans mon cas..

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr que le sens soit le même que "tu vas voir ta gueule", "Prends gare" étant plutôt un avertissement plutôt qu'une menace, et je pense que la chanson de Souchon signifie bien "tu vas voir ta gueule", mais réponse utile tout de même !

Answer (score -1):

Ça serait plutôt : "Cass' ta gueul' à la récré" et c'est ce que l'on entend lorsque l'on ne prête pas attention aux paroles de la chanson.
Cette expression était couramment utilisée pour proférer des menaces en classe vis-à-vis de condiciples.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language. FL n'est pas un forum mais un site de questions réponses et tu ne répond pas à la question qui demande « que signifie « t'ar » ? » qui est bien ce qui et dit et qu'on entend. Si tu n'entends pas la même chose ce n'est pas dans une réponse qu'il faut le dire mais dans un commentaire. Pour pouvoir faire des commentaires il faut avoir 50 de [réputation](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).  C'est vite acquis. Pour savoir comment fonctionne le site, c'est [par ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score -2):

Personnellement j'ai toujours compris "Barre ta gueule à la récré ".

Comment: C'est pourtant bel et bien « T'ar ta gueule à la récré » [paroles](https://www.paroles.cc/chanson,j-ai-dix-ans,9787)